# How I can take to human accent (Wavenet or Ssml voices)?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I am using this google cloud text to speech like they write in their website. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-text-speech-csharp/#6 )

But there are no details about how to take output Wavenet voices (Ssml) . This  coding output is normal voices.

My question is,  with this code, how I can  take to human accent (Wavenet or Ssml voieces)?

```
using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TextToSpeechApiDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();

            // The input to be synthesized, can be provided as text or SSML.
            var input = new SynthesisInput
            {
                **Text = "This is a demonstration of the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API"
            };
            // Build the voice request.
            var voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
            {
                LanguageCode = "en-US",
                SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Female**
            };

            // Specify the type of audio file.
            var audioConfig = new AudioConfig
            {
                AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3
            };

            // Perform the text-to-speech request.
            var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voiceSelection, audioConfig);

            // Write the response to the output file.
            using (var output = File.Create("output.mp3"))
            {
                response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. What do you mean that the coding output is "normal voices"? You are taking Ssml voices since you're defining `SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Female`.

Comment: ''NORMAL VOICES''  means is like computer voices.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) you can check the languages and voices supported in text-to-speech API. As described in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio#text-to-speech-text-python) the speech is characterized by three parameters: the `language_code`, the `name` and the `ssml_gender`.

You can employ the following Python code to translate the text `"Hello my name is John. How are you?"` into English with the accent `en-GB-Standard-A`

```
 def synthesize_text(text):                                                                                                                                                                       
     """Synthesizes speech from the input string of text."""                                                                                                                                      
     from google.cloud import texttospeech                                                                                                                                                        
     client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()                                                                                                                                                   

     input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)                                                                                                                                    

     # Note: the voice can also be specified by name.                                                                                                                                             
     # Names of voices can be retrieved with client.list_voices().                                                                                                                                
     voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(                                                                                                                                             
         language_code='en-GB',                                                                                                                                                                   
         name='en-GB-Standard-A',                                                                                                                                                                 
         ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)                                                                                                                                   

     audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(                                                                                                                                               
         audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)                                                                                                                                     

     response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)                                                                                                                         

     # The response's audio_content is binary.                                                                                                                                                    
     with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:                                                                                                                                                        
         out.write(response.audio_content)                                                                                                                                                        
         print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')                                                                                                                                      


 text="Hello my name is John. How are you?"                                                                                         
 synthesize_text(text)
```

I am not familiar with C# language but judging by the [C#](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/texttospeech/api/TextToSpeech/TextToSpeech.cs#L280) and [java](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/texttospeech/v1beta1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/texttospeech/v1beta1/model/VoiceSelectionParams.html) documentations you should be able to define the name parameter as well to tune the speech.